# not rendering color lwjgl voxel engine

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

i am writing a opengl based voxel engine voxel engine using java and lwjgl. i have followed [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/voxelenginelwjglport/home) and tried to update it's rendering method to modern opengl so i can use shaders. when i turned glVertexPointer into glVertexAttribPointer it displayed all the vertices correctlly but when i did it for glTexCoordPointer the color stopped displaying.

here are the two rendering methods of the chunks (from the updated one and the old one)

```
public void Render() { //updated render method 
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(VAOHandle);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE
                    * CHUNK_SIZE * 24);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
}

public void Render() {  //old render method 
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertexHandle);
        GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOColorHandle);
        GL11.glColorPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
        GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUADS, 0, CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE
                * CHUNK_SIZE * 24);

        GL11.glPopMatrix();
}
```

and here is the part where the date is loaded to the VAO/VBOs (the data is the same in both cases so i don't think i need to add it, but if needed i will):

```
// updated method
VAOHandle =  GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
VBOColorHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();
VBOVertexHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();

GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertexHandle);
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexPositionData,
                GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOColorHandle);
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexColorData, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

// old method
VBOColorHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();
VBOVertexHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();

GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOVertexHandle);
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexPositionData,
        GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOColorHandle);
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexColorData,
        GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

if anyone can figure out why the vertices are rendered but no color is applied i would be greatful, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have anything in your code to ensure that locations 0 and 1 correspond to the positions and colors in your shader code?

Comment: @RetoKoradi i haven't written my shader code yet, just add support for it, could that be it?

Comment: Yes. Generic vertex attributes, which is what you are using now, only work with shaders. As long as you're using the fixed pipeline, `glVertexPointer()` and `glColorPointer()` were the right calls.

Comment: @RetoKoradi ok thanks, didn't know that